# MS Access2007: How to update Date/Time value in a table using update query

Tags: ms-access-2007

```
    IIf("Duration"=1,DateAdd("m",[testTable]![Starting date],11),IIf

("Duration"=2,DateAdd("m",[testTable]![Starting date],23),DateAdd("m",

[testTable]![Starting date],5)))
```

I am trying to update a field I named End Date. 
I created an update query with the above code entered in the Update To: field.
An error occurs when I run it stating that Access cannot update the said fields.
Am I using the code wrong? Or should I try updating the said field in a different way?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you please post the full query you are using?

Comment: Is Duration a field name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few errors in the Query. First the DateAdd function takes in arguments in the following order. The interval to add (day, month or year etc), then the Number of Days/Months/Years to add. Followed with the date you want to add this number to.

The next error you have is, duration. If it is a field name it should be treated the same way you have treated the start date. So based on the corrections your code becomes.

```
UPDATE 
    testTable 
SET 
    testTable.endDateField = IIf(
                                testTable.Duration = 1, 
                                    DateAdd("m", 11, testTable.[Starting date]), 
                                IIf(
                                    testTable.Duration = 2, 
                                        DateAdd("m", 23, testTable.[Starting date]), 
                                    DateAdd("m", 5, testTable.[Starting date])
                                    )
                                );
```

On the other hand I would suggest you to create a table with the Duration and the number of days to add in another column something like.

```
durationNo  |   noOfMonths
------------+--------------
1           |   11
2           |   23
3           |   5
```

Then your update Query could be simplified with a JOIN, without the use of an IIF.

Hope this helps !